# Boostrap dropdown menu not working on CERTAIN iphones

Tags: iphone, ios, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

This recently launched, bootstrap-based (actually joostrap) website: http://www.lenspolitica.net/ have a weird problem with its drop-down menu when in mobile mode. Some people with iphones are reporting that the drop-down menu isn't working, while it is working with others iphones. 
While testing it myself with one of these non-working iphones,the only thing I noticed is that the menu would actually work while the page is still in the process of loading. Then the button isn't just responding at all.

The only other thing I could think of would be some hidden iframes placed on top of the website for a social sharing plugin.

Any hints/advices very welcome. Thank you very much.

I could try to test all kind of tricks I have found on this forum or elsewhere, but as the site is working well on my iphone, I have no ways of testing the result of these attempts. Therefore I decided to post this question to acquire a little expert advice.